# Time Dilation In Between Two Objects

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

Suppose an object A is exactly halfway in between two identical objects B and C, so the magnitude of the cumulative acceleration on object A is $0$. Objects A, B, and C have no velocity relative to each other. Will the time dilation for object A be the same as if there was one object with the mass of objects B and C combined, or the same as if objects B and C did not exist?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question, but has object A got any relative velocity,  ignoring acceleration for the moment, compared to B or C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gravitational time dilation is not caused by acceleration. In most situations it is related to how deep the gravitational potential well is.

So if two stars are orbiting you at a distance $d$ you will experience more gravitational time dilation than if you were a distance $d$ away from just one of them.

So the time dilation is cumulative.

Thus there will not be zero time dilation and it will generally be as strong as if there was one larger mass nearby.

Comment: Wow thats fascinating. I guess that means electric charge doesn't bend space-time? Other wise the cumulative effects would be enormous?

Comment: @Alex Electric charges totally bend spacetime. But only through their nonzero energy and momentum and stress and from having nonzero electromagnetic fields that themselves have nonzero energy momentum and stress. I have zero idea why you conclude they don't. This question didn't even talk about charges.

Comment: @Timaeus The OP stated that the point of interest is *between* the two objects (stars). That would create a saddle point would it not? Would the gravitational well be shallower or deeper than for a single star? I'm musing that it would be shallower than a single star of double mass (but maybe not).

Comment: Yeah ... I got caught up in thinking about forces (vectors) instead of the (scaler) energy.  It's Friday, and I'm tired. :P